# How did Luke get his lightsaber back after A New Hope?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, a-new-hope, luke-skywalker, the-empire-strikes-back

After Vader kills Obi-Wan on the Death Star, his lightsaber falls at Vader's feet. Luke witnesses from a distance and escapes on the Falcon. The rest of the movie plays out, but that's the last we see of the blue lightsaber. The next time it appears, Luke is hacking himself free from the Wampa's clutches at the beginning of *The Empire Strikes Back*.

My question is...how did he get it back?  Did Darth Vader overnight it to Luke through UPS?

I have scoured the internet and found no mention of it. There is common consensus that it **is** the same lightsaber, so...
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see that as widely accepted. Obiwan is a Jedi with his own saber. The one Luke gets used to belong to Obiwan's padawan, Anakin.

Comment: I did wonder this for a time when I first saw the films if it makes you feel any better.

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was about as solid as it gets. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Comment: Clearly... he used the force. ;)

Answer (score 28):

### Luke's lightsaber/s

Luke uses the same [lightsaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Skywalker%27s_lightsaber) throughout the first two films in the Original Trilogy, the same one that Obi-Wan took from Anakin at the end of their duel in *Revenge of the Sith* and that Luke was then [given in Ben's shack](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/34/71/7a/34717a4d7e09a3c7975e6ecd1926f562.jpg) on Tatooine.

Eventually he loses it, along with his hand in a duel with Vader at the end of *The Empire Strikes Back* and constructs a [second lightsaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker%27s_green_lightsaber) sometime between the end of the second film and the start of the third.

---

The following images are from the [Star Wars: Visual Dictionary](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0756622387). The first is labelled "*Skywalker's Lightsaber*", the latter "*Luke's Second Lightsaber*"

[image: Two lightsabers used by Luke Skywalker, above the one given to him by Obi-Wan on Tatooine in A New Hope, which is silver, mostly cylindrical with radiator-type fins near the butt and some buttons near the beveled top. Below the one constructed by Luke before the start of Return of the Jedi, which is silver near the base with a raised rectangular section, then a stack of alternating black and silver bands, then a narrow copper-coloured throat before a wider silver base of the blade]

### Obi-Wan's lightsaber/s

Obi-Wan wields the same lightsaber throughout *A New Hope*, one that he constructed between the end of *Star Wars: Attack of the Clones* and the start of the animated *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* TV show, evidently in honour of his  [becoming a Jedi Master](https://www.starwars.com/databank/obi-wan-kenobis-lightsabers).

[image: Obi-Wan's lightsaber with a band of rectangular studs at the bottom, a cylindrical black section with a raised button, a silver barrel portion with a gold detail, a corrugated section in black and then narrow copper and black sections before the silver base of the blade] [image: Still of Obi-Wan, with medium-length brown beard and hair in Jedi garb, wielding his blue lightsaber]

---

As an aside, you may wish to note that Obi-Wan's lightsaber evidently survived the duel with Darth Vader. While there is no further Disney-canon information about it, there's a rich seam of "Legends" stories that detail its fate, passing through several hands before finally ending up back in Luke's possession as part of his New Jedi Order.

Comment: Agreed.  When Luke and C-3PO walk into the bar at Mos Eisley (when the bartender is like, "we don't serve their kind here") you can clearly see Luke with his daddy's lightsaber hanging from his belt.  Shortly thereafter, somebody picks on Luke and Obi-wan slices off his arm...with his own lightsaber.

Comment: Ok. Did not even consider the possibility that Obiwan has his own saber (duh). Just saw Kenobi using a blue lightsaber and figures it was the same. I now feel dumb for posting

Comment: @compkd75 - There are no foolish questions if they lead you to a greater understanding of something you love.

Comment: @Richard - Having watched the questions on this board for a while, I have to disagree.

Comment: "he constructed between the end of Star Wars: The Clone Wars and the start of Revenge of the Sith" don't you mean "he constructed between the end of Star Wars: *Attack of the Clones* and the start of Revenge of the Sith"? Kenobi used that saber during the whole clone wars cgi film and show.

Comment: @RedCaio - You are, of course correct. Edited accordingly and a pic added

Comment: Curious that the starwars.com page says his first lightsaber had a green blade (that Darth Maul kicked into the pit) and then right below has a video show it was in fact blue.

Comment: @MichaelItzoe - Clearly just a typo. I've twittered at the webmaster for the site. Hopefully they'll correct it.

Comment: @MichaelItzoe - They've corrected it now, to say that it had a blue blade

Comment: Very late I know, but it might be worth mentioning that the Luke/Anakin sabre was almost certainly left on the Falcon for the bulk of the action in ANH. Last we see of it in that movie, it's on Luke's belt when they climb out of the smuggling compartments. It's not part of the trooper disguise for obvious reasons, nor his costume after the trash compactor scene. It's possible Hamill was wearing as part of his costume it in the Yavin arrival & briefing scenes, but he's wearing the poncho/sat down respectively, so probably not. Curious that he's not even wearing it for the award ceremony scene.