# What happened to Obi Wan's lightsaber after the duel between Obi-Wan and Darth Vader on the Death Star?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

What happened to Obi-Wan Kenobi's lightsaber after Obi-Wan and Darth Vader dueled on the Death Star? Vader seemed to have possession of it the last time we saw it -- what did he do with it? Did it survive

> the destruction of the Death Star?

---

Note: the idea for this question came from http://www.moviemistakes.com/film1226/questions/entry56487

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe. And I'm sure I wrote an answer for the dupe. Aargh!

Comment: @Jonah - I'm convinced. If I recall, there's nothing in the main canon, but it turns up loads of times in the EU.

Comment: @Richard, Jonah: a quick search threw up [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/75852/where-are-obi-wan-kenobis-and-qui-gon-jinns-lightsabers) and [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67556/where-is-obi-wans-lightsaber).

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Neither one of those seems to be quite it. One asks about what happened after the fight with Maul, and the other is similar.

Comment: @Jonah - This was the question I was thinking of; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122003/how-did-luke-get-his-lightsaber-back-after-a-new-hope/122006. It answers this question, but only incidentally.

Comment: i trust Jonah's answers.. his always right his the Legend here..

Comment: This site isn’t just for Jonah to answer your questions. I would take RedCaio’s advice if I were you.

Comment: yes man.. i sad i m always happy with Jonah answers.. others also can answer..

Comment: it's fair to assume that Vader took it. but when Vader left the Death Star, he didn't expect to be destroyed - so he would have no reason to bring it with him. he probably left it in his quarters and it was destroyed with the first death star.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Canon

**I don't think there is an answer in canon.** Obi-Wan's lightsaber was left when Vader killed him. It may have been destroyed in the explosion of the Death Star, or Vader or someone else may have taken it (as in Legends), but its canon status after *A New Hope* is unknown.

However, there is a Legends answer.

### Legends

**In Legends, Vader did indeed keep Obi-Wan's saber as a trophy.**

> “Darth Vader…,” Luke said.
>
> It surprised him that Darth Vader would want to keep the lightsaber of
> his former teacher, but it wasn’t impossible. Vader could have sent it
> away from the Death Star just after he defeated Kenobi. Or he might
> even have taken it with him when he escaped the destruction of the
> Death Star.
>
> —*Junior Jedi Knights: Vader's Fortress*

**Later, Luke retrieves it.**

> “It’s good to have you back, Artoo,” Luke said. “From all the
> excitement, I take it you found the lightsaber.”
>
> “And more,” Tionne answered, holding out the Holocron for him to see.
> “Master Ikrit has the lightsaber with him.”
>
> —*Junior Jedi Knights: Vader's Fortress*

**A minor character named Orloc tries to steal it later on, but is ultimately unsuccessful**:

> "You would have killed my friends—and maybe even me—just to keep the
> Holocron and Obi-Wan Kenobi's lightsaber. You thought they could give
> you true power, just like I believed you could give me real power. The
> power of the Force is real. But you knew you never had it. I was the
> fool."
>
> —*Junior Jedi Knights: Kenobi's Blade*

Comment: Legends is the real canon anyway.

Answer (score 11):

#### Canon: We don't know

> Obi-Wan Kenobi's lightsaber was the third lightsaber that was constructed and wielded by Jedi Master Obi-Wan Kenobi during the Clone Wars after he lost second one prior to the Battle of Geonosis.
>   - [source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi%27s_lightsaber_(Jedi_Master))

That's about all we know about it at this point, Lucasfilm (Disney) has yet to expand on the lightsaber's final fate, so it is unknown in canon at this point. **It was last seen  on the floor of the first Death Star with Kenobi's Jedi robes.**

[image]

Answer (score -2):

It seems there was sufficient time for Vader to take the lightsaber and keep it on his person under his cape. When the Death Star exploded he would have returned to Mustafar to bring his trophy back to where that very lightsaber was used to take his limbs.

Answer (score -4):

I personally think that Vader would have kept the lightsaber and robes as a reminder that the light always succumbs to the dark. If I were him, I would have kept it at a private base or room. Whether it will be discovered, however. . .

Comment: While an interesting theory we're looking fir canonically supported answers, take a look at the [answer] page to learn more